# Openlayers 3 set map view - passing variable values

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3

I have an application that uses a coordinate zoom tool based on Openlayers 3.18 - the user enters two coordinate values in a form, on clicking the submit button the map then uses these values to zoom the map to the location of the coordinates using the center option.

In Openlayers 3.19, this tool has stopped working and the map just hangs and freezes without giving me an error message in the console.

The below is the javascript code I am using, with 'coord-x' and 'coord-y' div ids from the form's text boxes.

Is there anything wrong with how I do this? If I manually type in coordinate values in the center option below then it works ok, it just doesn't seem to pass the values correctly through to the setView function.

```
//Zoom map on coordinate zoom button click
$("#coord-zoom-btn").click(function() {
    var x = document.getElementById('coord-x').value;
    var y = document.getElementById('coord-y').value;
    map.setView(new ol.View({
        projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:27700'),
        resolutions: [28.0, 14.0, 7.0, 3.5, 1.75, 0.875, 0.4375, 0.21875, 0.109375],
        center: [x, y],
        resolution: 0.21875
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to include parseInt around my variables to make sure they are integers (this didn't seem to be an issue in previous versions).

So...

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('coord-x').value);
var y = parseInt(document.getElementById('coord-y').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had this solved on another thread for latest version. Use parseFloat().

```
var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('coord-x').value);
var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById('coord-y').value);
```